# Stopping jquery running after event is handled

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a radio button  which launch a jquery script on click.  On click I render a form where I want the user to enter a comment.  Evrything works fine,  event is detected and form is rendered  but when I click on the form field, it seems that it runs again my jquery script and I get the undefined variable.

Here is my radio button

```
<div class="switch">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view<?php echo $data['id'];?>" 
      value="Yes" id="yes<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" 
      data-comment="<?php echo $comment_state;?>" data-val=1>
      <label for="yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view<?php echo $data['id'];?>" 
      value="No" id="no<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" <?php echo $neutral; ?>
      data-opinion="<?php echo $comment_state;?>" data-val=0>
      <label for="no" >No</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
</div>
<div id="form<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"> </div>    // where I render the form after click
```

here is the jquery script

```
$('[id^="yes"], [id^="no"])').click(function(e) {


            var comment = $(this).data('comment');   // comment= 0 because not selected
            var val = $(this).data('val');           // val = 1 if I click yes
            var parameter = $(this).attr('name');    // parameter = view + id number
            parameter = parameter.replace('view','');

            if (comment ==0){   // New record
                $.ajax( 
                {

                    url : 'post/comment',
                    type: "POST",

                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                        {
                            $(".switch input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
                            $("#form"+ parameter).html(data);   
                        },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                        {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                });
            }
    });
```

Here is the form rendered

```
<div class="row">
     <label for="MyComment" class="required">Comment <span class="required">*</span></label>       
     <input size="60" maxlength="140" name="MyComment" id="Post_comment" type="text" />  
</div>
```

When I click on the field form or elsewhere,  I got the error   TypeError: parameter is undefined
(in the jquery script)

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to stop the event propagation?

Comment: yes I tried e.stopProgagation();  at last line of success but it does not have effect  @Madhu

Comment: `TypeError: parameter is undefined` on which line ?

Comment: @PriyankPatel  at line parameter = parameter.replace('view','');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('[id^="yes"], [id^="no"])').click(function(e) {
```

Try:

```
$("input.switch-input:radio").click(function(e) {
```

Comment: In the mean time, I found a solution by unbinding event after rendering the form.  But your solution is more elegant.  Thank you